# Jinja2 prevent Autoescaping for entire Pandas Tables

Tags: pandas, jinja2

Pandas comes with a handy df.to_html which covert the df into a Html Table.But when the df_html is fed to Jinja2 (for additional styling/text),it's autoescaping behavior coverts <> to &lt &gt.
***Safe/Markupsafe can't be implemented directly as the output is not a single html tag but mulitple tags in the html table buffer***.
Is there a simpler way to achieve autoescape safe html instead of parsing the whole html and replacing the &lt &gt back to <>?

```
Output :


pandas_html_buffer   
colorTxt_2 = "12<span class="greenColor">Green</span>","3453<span class="redColor">Red</span>"  

jinja 2 conversion   
<td>"12&lt;span class="greenColor"&gt;Green&lt;/span&gt;","3453&lt;span class="redColor"&gt;Red&lt;/span&gt;"</td>
```

***jinja2 template:***

```
{# templates/dfTablesTemplate.html #}
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tables.css"/>
</head>
<body> 
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">

    {{df_html_buf|safe}}
    
</div>
  
</body>
```

pandas_html_buffer:

```
import re
import pandas as pd  
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from markupsafe import escape


colorTxt_2  = ""

def Greenspan(x):
    return f'<span class="greenColor">{x}</span>' 

def Redspan(x):
    return f'<span class="redColor">{x}</span>' 

def htmlTemplate_out(htmlTable_buf,htmlpath_out):
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("jinjaTest\\templates\\"))
    template = env.get_template("dfTablesTemplate.html")
    _template = template.render(df_html_buf= htmlTable_buf)
    # print(_template)

    with open(htmlpath_out , "w") as fh:
        fh.write(_template)



def main():
    colorTxt = '"12Green","3453Red"'

  
    colorTxt_1 = re.sub(r"\BGreen\w*", lambda match: Greenspan(match.group(0)),f'{colorTxt}')
    colorTxt_2 = re.sub(r"\BRed\w*", lambda match: Redspan(match.group(0)),f'{colorTxt_1}')

    print(f"colorTxt_2 = {colorTxt_2}")

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Row":["1"],"Values":[colorTxt_2],})


    df_html_buf = df.to_html()
    # df_html_buf = escape(df_html_buf)

    print(f"df_html_buf  = {df_html_buf }")

    df_html_path = "jinjaTest.html"

    htmlTemplate_out(df_html_buf,df_html_path)

main()
```